# Multi threading in Java. Countdown and timer both at once

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Both the timer and the countdown method work when they are run individually. They also work as two individual threads however the priority of the thread sequences is causing the count down and the timer(counting up) not to be accurate.

Here is the sample output:cookie 10
cookie 9
cookie 8
seconds 1
cookie 7
seconds 2
seconds 3
cookie 6
seconds 4
cookie 5
seconds 5
cookie 4
cookie 3
seconds 6
cookie 2
seconds 7
cookie 1
seconds 8
seconds 9
seconds 10
seconds 11
seconds 12
seconds 13
seconds 14
seconds 15
seconds 16
seconds 17
seconds 18
seconds 19

Once the cookie timer is done the timer should continue as it does however while both timer and countdown are active the threads should keep track of the time in seconds without loosing accuracy. At the moment I am relying on the console to display this counts however I will be programming this in a graphical interface that will show the user the countdown and timer. Perhaps execution of the threads need to alternate between them in order for the timers to progress equally, in addition they should be synchronized so that one can not continue without the other. Any tips on implementation. Thanks.

public class Console {

```
     long lastTime;
     boolean counting = true;
     boolean cCounting = true;
     long seconds = 0;
     long delta = 0;
     volatile int startNumber = (int) Level.cookieTime / 1000;
    Thread countDown;
    Thread time;

    public Console() {

        counting = Game.enter;

        cookieCountDown();
        timer();
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void timer() {

        time = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                seconds = 0;


                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    counting = Game.enter;

                    while (counting) {

                        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        delta = now - lastTime;

                        if (delta >= 1000) {

                            delta = 0;
                            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            System.out.println("seconds " + seconds); //Print seconds
                            seconds++;

                            if (!counting){
                                System.out.println("stoped"  + counting);
                                //time.stop();
                              //  return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        time.start();

    }

    public void cookieCountDown() {
        countDown = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Player.cCounting = true;

                while (startNumber != 0) {
                    startNumber = (int) Level.cookieTime / 1000;
                    cCounting = Game.enter;

                    while (startNumber > 0 && cCounting) {
                        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        delta = now - lastTime;

                        if (delta >= 1000) {
                            delta = 0;
                            lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            System.out.println("cookie " + startNumber);// print countdown;
                            startNumber--;

                            if (!Player.cCounting) {
                                Player.cCounting = true;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        countDown.start();

        if (startNumber == 0 || !Player.cCounting) {

            Player.cCounting = true;
            startNumber = (int) Level.cookieTime / 1000;

        }
    }


    public void setCounting(boolean counting) {
        this.counting = counting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on a "counter" to track the seconds, actually use the duration.  A simple solution would be to use two `Instant`'s to determine when the counter was started and the current time, which can calculate the `Duration` between them.  From this you can use a second `Duration`, which represents the total amount of time the countdown runs for, and calculate the remaining time

Comment: there is no sleep or wait in either while loop. This code will be a cpu hog.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to eventually display the timer and the countdown to the user it is not enough just to calculate the duration.

Comment: @gagansingh can you explain your comment a bit further.

Comment: @MichaelGonzalez I don't see why not - using the date/time API will give you more then enough information to provide a "countdown" output, I do it all the time, in fact, I did a quick just before with 100 threads counting down over different durations without any issues. This approach takes into greater account situations where "lag" might be an issue, as it's based on time, not how fast the loop can be executed

Comment: @MadProgrammer after reading your comment multiple times I understand what you are suggesting. I realize it is a better way to obtain the count down. However, I also believe my issue is a thread priority issue. If you see my sample output the threads interfere with one another causing the counting for both the timer and the countdown to lose accuracy.

Comment: Which raises the issue of why you need multiple threads. You can accomplish the same thing with a single thread and multiple “countdown” classes, which the single thread would “tick”. As has been commented, your threads are free wheeling (run as fast as the cpu can run them) which starve other threads. An important concept in multithreading - more threads don’t always mean more work getting done faster

Comment: you need to sleep in between each while loop. The thread will be spinning in the while loop without waiting and that prevents other threads from getting cpu time. Try putting Thread.sleep(50) in the beginning of the both the while loop.

Comment: @MadProgrammer so let me clarify I can use one thread with a tick of one second to do both the countdown and the timer. I can use the date/time api to get the duration of when a counter instance is created. I will use the tick to check for the current time every second. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @MichaelGonzalez I might use half a second, but basically, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free wheeling loops in threads puts a considerable load on the CPU which can have an adverse affect on other threads.  Remember, more threads doesn't always mean more work gets done faster.

What's needed is some way to "yield" time, so the CPU can better schedule other threads.

Since you're only interested in a second accuracy, using a `sleep` of half a second is a good place to start.  This greatly reduces the amount of time that each threads needs on the CPU.

Personally, when dealing with time based solutions like this, I prefer to use the date/time API, as it generally produces a better and more reliable solution, but that's me.

The following example simply starts 10 threads, each with a 5 second timeout.  Each thread sleeps for half a second before running through it's prescribed logic

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() throws InterruptedException {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new Timeout(5, "Cookie " + index));
            t.start();
        }

        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    public class Timeout implements Runnable {

        private Duration duration;
        private Instant startTime;
        private String label;

        public Timeout(int count, String label) {
            duration = Duration.ofSeconds(count);
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long time = Long.MAX_VALUE;
            try {
                startTime = Instant.now();
                while (true) {
                    Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
                    Duration remainingTime = duration.minus(runTime);
                    // You could also use remainingTime.getSeconds() == 0, but it
                    // depends on your desired level of accuracy
                    if (remainingTime.isNegative()) {
                        System.out.println("Out of time");
                        return;
                    } else {
                        if (time != remainingTime.getSeconds()) {
                            time = remainingTime.getSeconds();
                            System.out.println(label + " " + duration.getSeconds() + "/" + time);
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produced an output similar to...

```
Cookie 3 5/5
Cookie 4 5/5
Cookie 0 5/5
Cookie 1 5/5
Cookie 2 5/5
Cookie 6 5/5
Cookie 9 5/5
Cookie 5 5/5
Cookie 7 5/5
Cookie 8 5/5
Cookie 1 5/4
Cookie 5 5/4
Cookie 7 5/4
Cookie 6 5/4
Cookie 2 5/4
Cookie 0 5/4
Cookie 3 5/4
Cookie 4 5/4
Cookie 8 5/4
Cookie 9 5/4
//...
Cookie 5 5/1
Cookie 3 5/1
Cookie 0 5/1
Cookie 7 5/1
Cookie 1 5/1
Cookie 2 5/1
Cookie 6 5/1
Cookie 8 5/1
Cookie 4 5/1
Cookie 9 5/1
Cookie 5 5/0
Cookie 7 5/0
Cookie 4 5/0
Cookie 8 5/0
Cookie 0 5/0
Cookie 2 5/0
Cookie 3 5/0
Cookie 1 5/0
Cookie 6 5/0
Cookie 9 5/0
Out of time
Out of time
Out of time
Out of time
Out of time
Out of time
Out of time
Out of time
Out of time
Out of time
```

Another solution might be to use a single thread and a `List` of "timers".  The thread would "tick" the timers, which would allow them to determine how long they've been running and it they have expired or not, for example...

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() throws InterruptedException {
        List<Timeout> timers = new ArrayList<>(10);
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            timers.add(new Timeout(5, "Cookie " + index));
        }

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    Iterator<Timeout> it = timers.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Timeout timer = it.next();
                        timer.tick();
                        if (timer.isTimedOut()) {
                            it.remove();
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.yield();
                    if (timers.isEmpty()) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    public class Timeout {

        private Duration duration;
        private Instant startTime;
        private String label;

        private Long lastTime;
        private boolean timedOut;

        public Timeout(int count, String label) {
            duration = Duration.ofSeconds(count);
            this.label = label;
        }

        public boolean isTimedOut() {
            return timedOut;
        }

        public void tick() {
            if (timedOut) {
                return;
            }
            if (startTime == null) {
                startTime = Instant.now();
            }
            Duration runTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
            Duration remainingTime = duration.minus(runTime);
            // You could also use remainingTime.getSeconds() == 0, but it
            // depends on your desired level of accuracy
            if (remainingTime.isNegative()) {
                System.out.println("Out of time");
                timedOut = true;
            } else {
                if (lastTime == null || lastTime != remainingTime.getSeconds()) {
                    lastTime = remainingTime.getSeconds();
                    System.out.println(label + " " + duration.getSeconds() + "/" + lastTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I might even add in a couple of methods to return the "duration" of the timer, the running time and the amount of time remaining, but that's me.

The drawback to this is, if the "main" thread takes too long, a timer could expire before the next check cycle.  In the above example, I've basically allowed the thread to run as fast as possible (I did add a `yield`, but still not my favourite thing to do) and simply looped through the list of "timer"s until all the timers had expired.

Which solution is better?  Depends on your circumstances.  Personally, I tend to aim for a single fast running thread (I tend to use `Thread.sleep(5)`, but that's just me) which can iterate over a series of "things to be done".  With the above example, because we're relying on time based solutions (and not counters), even if we have some lag, we're still getting a (reasonably) accurate result